# routerLink stopped working in @angular/cli

Tags: angular-cli, routerlink

I just updated my project from `angular-cli` to release version `@angular/cli`. Everything was working fine before but after upgradation, It stopped working. If I remove `routerLink` then it works fine. Please help me to solve this.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/register']">Signup</a>
```

I am updating `RouterModule` as below.

```
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

**package.json :**

```
"@angular/router": "^3.4.0"
```

Comment: Can you share your router module?

Comment: I guess your syntax is wrong. I'd use plain:`<a routerLink="/register">..`. See: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html